# MailChimp bad request JSONParseError with Python

Tags: python, django, api, mailchimp

I am trying to hook up to MailChimp's api, in my Django application, to add an email to one of my lists. Seems pretty simple enough. I add my api key to the header of the request, with the email address and other variable in the body of the request. every time I try and connect though, I get a response status code of 400. The message says there is a JSON parsing error, and that my JSON is either formatted incorrectly, or there is missing data required for the request. I am making this same api call however with Postman, and am getting a good response back.

view function

```
import requests

def join_newsletter(request, email):
    # hash the user's email for mailchimp's API
    # m = hashlib.md5()
    # c_email = email
    # m.update(c_email.encode('utf-8'))
    # email_hash = m.hexdigest()

    api_key = 'apikey ' + settings.MAILCHIMP_API
    api_endpoint = api_endpoint

    data = {
        "email_address": email,
        "status": "subscribed"
    }

    header = {
        'Authorization': api_key
    }

    r = requests.post(api_endpoint, data=data, headers=header)

    message = r.content

    return message
```

Comment: perhaps try adding a `content-type: application/json` header and using the `json` module to serialize your data?

Comment: Do I add the header to the request or response object ? I tried adding content-type, and Content-Type to my request header with a value of application/json and I still got the bad request error. Do I use json's dump string method ?

Comment: add the 'content-type: application/json' in the same `header` dict as the `Authorization: api_key` bit. yes, `data = json.dumps(data)` would work.

Comment: Ahhh ! Finally it works haha. I tried serializing the request body data and the header, and it wasn't working, but only serializing the data as you said worked. Thank you n1c9 !

Comment: no problem, happy to help :-)